# Visual Studio doesn't always show refactoring possibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have some class variables and properies for them:

```
private ToolStrip _toolBar;

public ToolStrip ToolBar
{
   get { return _toolBar; }
}
```

Normaly, when I point mouse or cursor on them, VS suggests to refactor with

> "Use auto property"

After I've done this refactoring for one variable refactoring is not available anymore for other variables. It doesn't appear anymore as suggestion for some time. Only after few minutes it is available again. Did anyone face this issue too?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.4.2.

Comment: I think you're talking about Refactor that Resharper does? Do you have it installed? What if your license is valid or was in the trial period and expired?

Comment: @CelsoLívero no, I don't have ReSharper and no any other extentions for refactoring.